# Simulating cookies with python web crawler

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x

I need some help with this. I am trying to make a web crawler with the 'requests' lib as well as the BeautifulSoup4 lib but in order to successfully do that I have to visit a link to activate specific cookies that allow me search things of that query.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def web_spider(max_pages, query):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = r'http://website.com/search/index?page=' + str(page) + '&q=' + query
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.finaAll('a', {'class': 'comments_link'}):
            href = 'http://website.com/' + link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1
```

the problem is with certain querys, unless a certain cookie setting is triggered by a url, it won't display anything due to the correct cookies not being enabled. What would be the best course of action for me to take based on the current functionality of my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Session()` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and cookies will be handled automatically:

```
session = requests.Session()

def web_spider(max_pages, query):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://website.com/search/index'
        params = {'page': page, 'q': query}
        source_code = session.get(url, params=params)
        plain_text = source_code.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.select('a.comments_link[href]'):
            href = 'http://website.com/' + link['href']
            print(href)
        page += 1
```

The global `session` object now tracks all cookies.

I also altered your code to use the `params` parameter to have `requests` handle encoding, and you should use `response.content`, *not* `response.text` when parsing HTML, to make sure the correct encoding is detected *by BeautifulSoup*.

Comment: When I type in 'session = Session()' I get an error saying "Unresolved reference 'Session'"

Comment: i changed it to 'session = requests.Session()' is that fine?

Comment: @ThatBenderGuy: yes, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: One last question, where would I place the `session.get('http://website.com/cookieToggle')`?

Comment: Or better yet (sorry for so many questions) how do I view the current cookies python has stored for that session?

Comment: @ThatBenderGuy: `session.cookies` is a dictionary-like cookie jar.